# A tela de confirmação do Primeface não funciona

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, primefaces-3.5

Essa é a tela que aparece no meu Browser

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando aperto o botão de exclusão ele simplesmente não faz nada. Não gera nenhum erro no consoles do eclipse

Esse é o código separado

está problema aqui!

```
<p:column style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
                    <p:button icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar" />
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" oncomplete="confirmacaoExclusao.show()" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:confirmDialog header="Exclusão de produto" message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o produto?"
                widgetVar="confirmacaoExclusao">
                <p:button value="Não" onclick="confirmacaoExclusao.hide(); return false;" />
                <p:commandButton value="Sim" oncomplete="confirmacaoExclusao.hide();" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
```

código completo

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

    <ui:define name="titulo">Pesquisa Produtos</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="corpo">

        <h:form>
        <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />
            <h1>Pesquisa de Produtos</h1>

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top:20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="Pesquisa" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/produtos/CadastroProduto" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel"
                style="width:100%; margin-top:20px">

                <p:outputLabel value="SKU" for="sku" />
                <p:inputText id="sku" size="20" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome" />
                <p:inputText id="nome" size="80" />

            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:dataTable id="produtosTable"
                value="#{pesquisaProdutosBean.produtosFiltrados}" var="produto"
                style="margin-top: 20px" emptyMessage="Nenhum produto encontrado."
                rows="20" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                paginatorPosition="bottom">

                <p:column headerText="SKU" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
                    <h:outputText value="123" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Nome" >
                    <h:outputText value="Bola de morango" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Categoria" style="width: 250px">
                    <h:outputText value="Doces - bolas de chikedkemd"  />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Valor Unitário" style="text-align: right; width: 120px">
                    <h:inputText value="123" styleClass="moeda"/>
                </p:column> 

                <p:column headerText="Estoque" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
                    <h:outputText value="98" />

                </p:column> 

                <p:column style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
                    <p:button icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar" />
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" oncomplete="confirmacaoExclusao.show()" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:confirmDialog header="Exclusão de produto" message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o produto?"
                widgetVar="confirmacaoExclusao">
                <p:button value="Não" onclick="confirmacaoExclusao.hide(); return false;" />
                <p:commandButton value="Sim" oncomplete="confirmacaoExclusao.hide();" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

porque será que não a aparece a tela de confirmação?

esse aqui foram as mensagens que geraram no consoles

```
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:PeiddoVenda' did not find a matching property.
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Feb 15 2015 18:10:42 UTC
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         8.0.20.0
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            6.3
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_31-b13
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\workspace Web\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\workspace Web\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\workspace Web\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\workspace Web\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\workspace Web\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\workspace Web\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\endorsed
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;C:\eclipse\eclipse luna\eclipse;;.
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 1152 ms
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
mar 18, 2015 2:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
mar 18, 2015 2:08:44 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFORMAÇÕES: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [123] milliseconds.
mar 18, 2015 2:08:46 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMAÇÕES: Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.8-02 ( 20140915-1602 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8-02@13678) para o contexto '/PedidoVenda'
mar 18, 2015 2:08:47 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMAÇÕES: JSF1048: Anotações PostConstruct/PreDestroy presentes.  Os métodos ManagedBeans marcados com essas anotações informarão as anotações processadas.
mar 18, 2015 2:08:48 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
mar 18, 2015 2:08:48 PM org.primefaces.extensions.application.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: Running on PrimeFaces Extensions 3.0.0
mar 18, 2015 2:08:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mar 18, 2015 2:08:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mar 18, 2015 2:08:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 5017 ms
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E no log do navegador, aparece alguma coisa?

Comment: aonde especificamente você está se referindo?

Comment: Por exemplo, no Google Chrome, você pode ver o log pelo atalho Ctrl+Shift+j, e também pode executar instruções em JavaScript.

Comment: ata entendi, vou verificar

Comment: ver se isso ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando programar manualmente a chamada ao *confirmDialog*. A idéia não é essa. A idéia é que o *confirmDialog* substitua a confirmação padrão do JavaScript, então você programa o botão normalmente para fazer o que tem que fazer, e configura-o para que seja invocada uma confirmação quando o botão é clicado.

Então, você não precisa programar a chamada do *confirmDialog*. Ao invés, você configura o botão para que a janela de confirmação seja automaticamente invocada.

Seu código deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" 
                        actionListener="#{bean.excluir()}">
                        <p:confirm header="Exclusão de produto" 
                            message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o produto?" 
                            icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:confirmDialog global="true">
                <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" 
                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" 
                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
            </p:confirmDialog>
```

Veja as diferenças com relação ao seu código original:

- Eu dei uma função ao botão de excluir (neste caso, a chamada do método fictício *bean.excluir*, que será feita pelo Primefaces usando Ajax).
- Especifiquei uma tag *p:confirm* para o botão. Ela é responsável pelo acionamento do *confirmDialog*.
- *header* e *message* são especificados na tag *p:confirm*, pois o dialog é genérico.
- Adicionei a propriedade *global* ao *confirmDialog*. Este componente, por sua vez, não tem nenhuma ação explicitamente programada. São as classes *ui-confirmdialog-yes* e *ui-confirmdialog-no* nos botões que identificam qual botão o usuário clicou. Então, se o usuário clicar em *"Sim"*, o método associado ao botão *"Excluir"* (no caso, *bean.excluir*) será invocado.